# apply with lambda and apply without lambda

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

I am trying to use the `impliedVolatility` function in `df_spx.apply()` while hardcoding the variable inputs `S`, `K`, `r`, `price`, `T`, `payoff`, and `c_or_p`.

However, it does not work, using the same function `impliedVolatility`, only doing `lambda` + `apply` it works.

[code link][1]

```
# first version of code 

S = SPX_spot
K = df_spx['strike_price']
r = df_spx['r']
price = df_spx['mid_price']
T = df_spx['T_years']
payoff = df_spx['cp_flag']
c_or_p = df_spx["cp_flag"]

df_spx["iv"] = df_spx.apply(impliedVolatility(c_or_p, S, K, T, r,price),axis=1)


# second version of code 

df_spx["impliedvol"] = df_spx.apply(
    lambda r: impliedVolatility(r["cp_flag"],
                                S,
                                r["strike_price"],
                                r['T_years'],    
                                r["r"],
                                r["mid_price"]), 
    axis = 1)
```

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBfO5.png
```

Comment: `impliedVolatility(c_or_p, S, K, T, r,price)` *calls the function* and evaluates the to the return value of the function. `lambda x: ...` is a lambda expression which evaluates to a *function*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give apply a function that it can call. It needs a callable function. In your first example

```
df_spx.apply(impliedVolatility(c_or_p, S, K, T, r,price), axis=1)
```

you are giving the result of the function as a parameter to apply. That would not work. If you instead wrote

```
df_spx.apply(impliedVolatility, c_or_p=c_or_p, S=S, K=K, T=T, r=r, price=price, axis=1)
```

if the function keywords arguments have the same names or if you wrote

```
df_spx.apply(impliedVolatility, args=(c_or_p, S, K, T, r,price), axis=1)
```

then it might work. Notice we are not calling the `impliedVolatility` in the apply. We are giving the function as a argument.

Comment: thank you sir for unlocking my understanding !!

Comment: I'll appreciate it if you uv and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is already a pretty good answer, but maybe to give it a different perspective. The apply is going to loop on your data and call the function you provide on it.

Say you have:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": list("asd")})
df
Out: 
   a  b
0  1  a
1  2  s
2  3  d
```

If you want to create new data or perform certain work on any of the columns (you could also do it at the entire row level, which btw is your use case, but let's simplify for now) you might consider using apply. Say you just wanted to multiply every input by two:

```
def multiply_by_two(val):
    return val * 2

df.b.apply(multiply_by_two)  # case 1
Out: 
0    aa
1    ss
2    dd

df.a.apply(multiply_by_two)  # case 2
Out: 
0    2
1    4
2    6
```

The first usage example transformed your one letter string into two equal letter strings while the second is obvious. You should avoid using apply in the second case, because it is a simple mathematical operation that will be extremely slow in comparison to `df.a * 2`. Hence, my rule of thumb is: use apply when performing operations with non-numeric objects (case 1). **NOTE**: no actual need for a lambda in this simple case.

So what apply does is passing each element of the series to the function.
Now, if you `apply` on an entire dataframe, the values passed will be a data slice as a series. Hence, to properly apply your function you will need to map the inputs. For, instance:

```
def add_2_to_a_multiply_b(b, a):
    return (a + 2) * b

df.apply(lambda row: add_2_to_a_multiply_b(*row), axis=1)  # ERROR because the values are unpacked as (df.a, df.b) and you can't add integers and strings (see `add_2_to_a_multiply_b`)

df.apply(lambda row: add_2_to_a_multiply_b(row['b'], row['a']), axis=1)
Out: 
0      aaa
1     ssss
2    ddddd
```

From this point on you can build more complex implementation, for instance, using `partial` functions, etc. For instance:

```
def add_to_a_multiply_b(b, a, *, val_to_add):
    return (a + val_to_add) * b

import partial
specialized_func = partial(add_to_a_multiply_b, val_to_add=2)
df.apply(lambda row: specialized_func(row['b'], row['a']), axis=1)
```

Just to stress it again, avoid `apply` if you are performance eager:

```
# 'OK-ISH', does the job... but
def strike_price_minus_mid_price(strike_price, mid_price):
    return strike_price - mid_price

new_data = df.apply(lambda r: strike_price_minus_mid_price(r["strike_price"], r["mid_price"] ), axis=1)
```

vs

```
'BETTER'
new_data = df["strike_price"] - df["mid_price"]
```